# .Net: Passing values from JavaScript to C# without a Postback

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, devexpress

I making a .Net web app using a third party gridview(DevExpress web form ASPxGridView).

Lets say I have two grids(Grid1 and Grid2, both devexpress).

I am running into an issue where I need to update values in Grid2 based on which column is clicked on Grid1(during the onClick event).

I am able to capture the row and column in JavaScript but am not able to pass it back to my serverside code.

The grid has some settings tied to the edit mode, that if the page does a full postback, the grid loses its edits.

I have tried setting a HiddenField and calling a postback, but that erases edits in my grid. I have tried passing the variables to a static method , but I cannot access the controls on my page to update Grid2. I have looked into trying to do a callback instead of a postback, but it looks like callbacks are referencing Client-Side methods.

Does any one know of a way to pass a client-side variable to c# without a postback, or to call a non-static c# method from JavaScript? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You want to google AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

The most basic approach to do this would involve two parts, part 1) add an ajax js function on your your existing grid page to handle the click event and make the data request. Part 2) Code up a separate C# web page to receive your client-side Grid1-variable, process it accordingly, and then respond with the data for Grid2. Here's some pseudocode of what the ajax call might look like, hope it helps.

```
//in your javascript section
$("#Grid1Cell").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: '@Url.Action("GetGrid2Data", "SomeController")"?yourVar=' + encodeURI(yourVal), 
           //alternatively  url: "yourNonMVCpage.aspx?yourVar=" + encodeURI(yourVal), 
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      dataType: "json",
      success: function (response) {
          if (response.SomeValues == "blah") {
              $("#Grid2Cell").text(response.SomeValues); //update Grid2
          }
    }});
});
```

Comment: Thanks, a lot. I've seen this but thought it needed a static c# method to run. I'll give it a try. Thanks, again.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to "connect c#", it is necessary to perform a request to the server (using any of the available techniques - callback, postback, etc.).

If you need to refresh another control (Grid2) rendering during this request, the corresponding HTML content should be returned as a results of this request.

According to the provided description, you need to implement "cascaded grids" - i.e., update a dependent grid when changing a main grid. If so, use the approach illustrated in the https://github.com/DevExpress-Examples/how-to-show-detail-information-in-a-separate-aspxgridview-e70 example and force the dependent grid custom callback (and further refreshing) via the client-side PerformCallback method + handle the server-side CustomCallback event.

Comment: Wow, implementing this now. This seems like the solution that uses the most out of our current DevExpress controls and their built in callbacks. Looked everywhere and posted on DevExpress forums and couldn't find anything as concise as this. I'll mark this as the solution as soon as I get it implemented. Thanks again.

Comment: Tried this solution. The CustomCallback worked, but we ended up losing our batchmode edits. After researching some things, it looks like keeping "batchmode" grid edits after hitting the server is not something these controls can do. Probably moving this project to WinForms instead of web. Thanks anyway for the help.

Comment: I'd suggest that you contact DevExpress Support to find the best solution.

Comment: I tried the DevExpress support. Basically told that keeping batch mode edits to the grid after running server side code was not something this web grid could handle. Moved to WinForms and all of the tasks are much easier to handle there. Thanks.